# How to post file and other information to controller and save it in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an mvc project in which I need create a form in which I have to take "Name", "age" and an excel sheet. For that I created a table as:

```
create table pinfo(
sno constraint pk primary key,
name varchar(50),
age int,
upfile varbinary(max)
)
```

When I executed scaffold, a model was created with properties:

```
public int Sno { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public byte[] Upfile { get; set; }
```

I created another model as:

```
public int Sno { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public IFormFile Upfile { get; set; }
```

and created a view using **"create"** template of *visual studio*. Now when I fill the form (in the interface) and upload the file, the file (maybe) reaches to **upfile**, but this file is being shown as string. I am not getting how to process it, or convert it into byte array. And then put all these (Sno, Name, Upfile) in the new object of actual model and then save in the database.

Comment: Why do you want to store the file?, why not store the file in a directory and store the link to the file in your database.